# Enable windows Authentication only for one operation in wcf rest service

Tags: wcf

I have one wcf REST service, with 4 API's,one of API should be  only  called by windows Authenticated  users(windows authentication). where as the other 3 API's should be called by any users(Anonymous authentication), is there any way to do this?
please let me know...

Thanks in advance
krishnamohan

Comment: You can create a separate behaviour and binding combination and expose the APIs using the different combinations needed

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, iam doing some seeion managment also in my service, so i need All the API's in the same service, so i cannot create differnt bindings... is there anyother way ??